# String immutability in JavaScript and the split method

Tags: javascript

I thought primitives in JS were Immutable. I am working with a string.

In JavaScript, String values are immutable, which means that they cannot be altered once created e.g.

```
const myStr = "Bob";
myStr[0] = "J";
console.log(myStr);

const aStr = "Bob";
aStr = "Job";
console.log(aStr);
```

I don't understand why `myStr` won't change the string but `aStr` will and why the presence of object bracket notation for `myStr[0] = "J";` stops the string being changed. I mean aren't strings supposed to be immutable in the first place?

I'm following an exercise online in which the author states 'Since strings are immutable, the split method makes it easier to work with them.' [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) This literally means nothing to me - I thought that once string was created it's value was not able to be altered. Is there some kind of distinction between an object in memory and the actual string value? Pretty lost and need a through and simple explanation if anyone can help please?

```
const str = "Hello World";
console.log(str);
const bySpace = str.split(" ");
console.log(bySpace);
// Sets bySpace to ["Hello", "World"]

const otherString = "How9are7you2today";
console.log(otherString);
const byDigits = otherString.split(/\d/);
console.log(byDigits);
// Sets byDigits to ["How", "are", "you", "today"]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Strings *are* immutable. `aStr = "Job"` assigns an entirely new string to the `aStr` variable and discards the old string. However, since the *binding* is immutable (`const`) you should be getting an error for that.

Comment: Numbers are immutable, but you can do `x = 1; x = 2;` for the same reason. You're not changing the value of `1`, you're just changing the variable to contain a different number.

Comment: After re-reading the question...can you clarify what you understand as "immutable"? Because there seems to be some confusion there and I'm not sure your understanding is correct.

Comment: Okay no problem. I will clarify what I understand immutable to be in the question.

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` when `aStr = "Job";` happens.

Comment: `str.split(" ")` does not mutate the string it returns a new string which you are saving in `bySpace`

Comment: @Balaj Khan thanks that helps clear things up I wish the MDN docs told me this. There is no mention of this the docs for the method

Comment: Actually, it says: *"Return Value: An Array of strings, split at each point where the separator occurs in the given string."*

Comment: Yes but where is the mention it does not cause mutation? And it returns something new all together?

Comment: Well, yes, it could be more explicit, but since per nature of JS, strings are immutable, it's presumable that it doesn't mutate the *given string*, since it is just returning a new value: an *Array of strings*

Comment: Where we can we find a good index/website/resource for all JS methods and whether they mutate or not? Does this exist?

Comment: Well MDN does list them. It should explicitly mention it if a method mutates the object. If it doesn't, then this can be added, since it's a wiki, but my exprience is that it's pretty explicit about methods that cause mutations. And since strings are well known to be immutable, there is no real need to explicitly mention they don't cause mutation as that's already implicit with anything to do with strings.

Comment: @user1554264 for array methods https://doesitmutate.xyz/